# jdk7.0_80 installation problem in 14.04 LTS

Tags: jdk

I am new to ubuntu. I am trying to install `java 7` in `14.04 LTS`. I have a problem. I will list the activity that I have done. Kindly tell me where I went wrong.

```
Downloaded jdk-7u80-linux-i586.tar.gz
Created directory jvm in /usr/lib
mv Download/jdk*.gz /usr/lib/jvm
tar -xzvf jdk-7u80-linux-i586.gz
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java" 0
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac" 0
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac
```

added: 
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80 PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80:$PATH` 
in `/etc/profile`and restarted the system.

When I try to check the installed java I am getting the following problem.

```
$> which java
/usr/bin/java
$> java
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
$> java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is on this line:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80:$PATH
```

You need to add the `bin` directory to the `PATH`, because that's where the executables are:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:$PATH
```

And since you also defined `JAVA_HOME`, you could also use it here (to make it easier to read and change):

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

---

And by the way, there's no need to manually download and install, there are simpler ways to do it.

If you just need Java (not necessarily Oracle's Java), you could install OpenJDK:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

If you don't want OpenJDK, and it has to be Oracle, then just do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

You may also want to have a look about Java in the Ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java